# php script runs too many times

Tags: php, html

This is the XML code I use in index.html which calls the show_vote.php script.
I call this function in the body of index.html like this`<script>showVoteResult()</script>`. For some reason, in the CPU usage of my cpanel, it says the PHP files are requested over and over again and has exceeded the CPU usage limit. I need help understanding where I did wrong.

```html
function showVoteResult() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("currentVote").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","show_vote.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I want to also mention that for one version of my index.html I accidentally left the function calling in a setInterval(), but that version of index.html has been updated. Could it be possible that someone left the old page on and is still making those calls even though index.html is already updated?

Comment: I have solved my problem, it is exactly as what I described in my previous comment, someone left an buggy older version of the web page in their browser, and it was running all day and all night.